# Chef InSpec check an http request is failing [successfully]

Tags: testing, exception, chef-infra, infrastructure-as-code

I am writing some infrastructure testing in Chef InSpec & am not sure how to go about testing that a url is *not* accessible publicly. I have the following code snippet which I am currently using

```rb
environments = {
  :ops => "ops",
}

control "verify-not-accessible-publicly" do
  impact 1.0
  title "verify we are not publicly accessible"
  environments.each do |_, env|
    uri = "http://#{env}.internal.example.com"
    begin
      result = http(uri, ssl_verify: true, open_timeout: 2, read_timeout: 5, max_redirects: 0)
    rescue => e
      unless e.class == Faraday::ConnectionFailed
        raise e
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This isn't working quite like I expect. I don't think the `http(uri,...)` block is actually executed until it is passed into a describe function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use [http resource](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/resources/http/) with a `describe` block and matchers

```
describe http('url', auth: {user: 'user', pass: 'test'}, params: {params}, method: 'method', headers: {headers}, data: data, open_timeout: 60, read_timeout: 60, ssl_verify: true, max_redirects: 3) do
  its('status') { should eq number }
  its('body') { should eq 'body' }
  its('headers.name') { should eq 'header' }
end
```